# How to run two independent grunt-sass tasks

Tags: gruntjs

I have two files, that I want to have watched and compiled with sass independently:

- Task `sass:A` should run only if a file in `A` changes
- Task `sass:B` only if a file in `B` changes.

Both tasks are expensive. I don't want to have them executed if it's not necessary.

I expected something like this:

```js
sass: {
    A: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                'A/main.css': 'A/main.scss'
            }
        }
    },
    B: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                'B/main.css': 'B/main.scss'
            }
        }
    }
},
watch: {
    sass_A: {
        files: 'A/**/*.scss',
        tasks: ['sass:A']
    },
    sass_B: {
        files: 'B/**/*.scss',
        tasks: ['sass:B']
    }
}
```

But I must be missing something as my `.css` files don't get changed as expected.

Is there an approach to have two independent `grunt-sass` tasks running?

Comment: are your gruntfile.js and folders A & B in the same directory?

Comment: Yes. Project root contains: grunt.js, A, B (and others...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following setup you should be able to work.

You need to change the relative paths to target your files in folder `A` and your files in folder `B`.

But please note that the paths are relative to the `gruntfile.js`

```js
sass: {
    admin: {
        src: ['../scss/admin/style.scss'],
        dest: '../css/admin.min.css'
    },
    front: {
        src: ['../scss/front/style.scss'],
        dest: '../css/front.min.css'
    }
},
watch: {
    admin_scss: {
        files: [
            '../scss/admin/**/*.scss'
        ],
        tasks: [
            'sass:admin',
        ]
    },
    front_scss: {
        files: [
            '../scss/front/**/*.scss'
        ],
        tasks: [
            'sass:front'
        ]
    },
},
```

Comment: Thank you. The trick seems to be, that the structure dist: {files: { ... }} doesn't work inside the sub-Tasks. Your version works!

Comment: Perfect, glad you sorted the issue :)